# Security Update for Windows preventing Oracle Listener from running?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tns

For the last month I have installed and used Oracle 11 XE, but this morning I restarted my computer and installed new updates from Windows. Now I cannot get the database to work. I know this caused it because I was using SQL Developer right up until I restarted. I get this error when attempting to run in SQL Developer

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Vendor code 17002
```

I went to Service and made sure my OracleServiceXE was running, which it was. I tried starting "OracleXETNSListener" and got this message:

```
The OracleXETNSListener service on Local Computer started and then stopped.
Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services and programs.
```

I then went to CMD and typed "lsnrctl status" and got:

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<host name>)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC0)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

Now at this point, almost everything I googled told me to start the listener and if that doesn't work run as admin. I did both of those things, but it didn't work.

**running normally in cmd:**

```
Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

Unable to OpenSCManager: err=5
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error
```

**running as admin:**

```
Starting tnslsnr: please wait...
(note: it stalls for 2 minutes)
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

To complicate matters, my computer told me "We couldn't finish installing updates" and that makes me hesitant to uninstall the updates.

Comment: how about another reboot?

Comment: @kevinsky Rebooted twice, and restarted all the servers. Did not work

Comment: In your status output you've shown `<host name>`. If that is an actual name, and your `listener.ora` specifies the same name, does that still resolve correctly to your PC's IP address? Or if it actually shows an IP address not a name, and your `listener.ora` specifies a fixed IP address, has your PC acquired a different IP during reboot (from DHCP)?